# Как в контроллерe AngularJs запустить class (new Class) из фабрики

Tags: angularjs

Есть такой наглядный пример с  классом, который прекрасно работает.

```js
const ElemEvent = class {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  on(event) {
    [...this.elems].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
      s.addEventListener(event, () => {
        [...this.elems].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
          arr[i].classList.remove('div-active');
        })
        s.classList.add('div-active');
      })
    })
  }
}

new ElemEvent('.footer-wrapper-1 div').on('click');
new ElemEvent('.footer-wrapper-2 div').on('click');
```

```css
footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

footer>div.footer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.footer-wrapper>div {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.footer-wrapper>h2 {
  margin: 15px;
}

.div-active {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-wrapper footer-wrapper-1">
    <h2>Footer-wrapper1</h2>
    <div class="div-1">Div-1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper footer-wrapper-2">
    <h2>Footer-wrapper2</h2>
    <div class="div-1">Div-1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div-2</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Ни как не соображу, как этот же пример запустить в контроллере получив этот `Class` из фабрики

```js
let app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testCtrl-1', ($scope, $element, testFactory) => {
  $scope.testFactory = testFactory;
})
app.controller('testCtrl-2', ($scope, $element, testFactory) => {
  $scope.testFactory = testFactory;

  new ElemEvent('.footer-wrapper .div').on('click');
})



app.factory('testFactory', () => {
  return {
    ElemEvent: class {
      constructor(selector) {
        this.elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      }
      on(event) {
        [...this.elems].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
          s.addEventListener(event, () => {
            console.log(s);
            [...this.elems].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
              arr[i].classList.remove('div-active');
            })
            s.classList.add('div-active');
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

footer>div.footer-wrapper {
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
}

div.footer-wrapper>div {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: 3px solid cyan;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.footer-wrapper>h2 {
  margin: 15px;
}

.div-active {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<footer ng-app="app">
  <div class="footer-wrapper" ng-controller="testCtrl-1">
    <h2>Footer-wrapper1</h2>
    <div class="div-1">Div-1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper" ng-controller="testCtrl-2">
    <h2>Footer-wrapper2</h2>
    <div class="div-1 div">Div-1</div>
    <div class="div2 div">Div-2</div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

как же исправить ситуацию? Почему `Class` не определен?

Comment: потому что он свойство testFactory

Comment: @Grundy,  догадывался об этом и так тоже пробовал, `new testFactory.ElemEvent('.footer-wrapper div').on(event);` но получаю ошибку, что `ElemEvent не конструктор`

Comment: только что попробовал это в твоем сниппете - все ок: `new testFactory.ElemEvent('.footer-wrapper .div').on('click')` отлично отрабатывает

Comment: @Grundy, У меня в примере, видать еще где-то ошибка была... Я пример `(тут)` не скопировал из своего, а написал, тут работает, а там нет..  Благодарю, разобрался...   Напиши ответом подробным, думаю будет интересно

Comment: Сам пиши, я бы предложил закрыть как не воспроизводится, так как в приведенном коде ошибка действительно не воспроизводится

Comment: @Grundy, а фабрики могут между собой взаимодействовать? Дума. что нет, но все же.....Лучше переспросить...

Comment: Могут, а почему нет?

Comment: Да...??? Мне казалось, что они могут что-то отдать, но не принимать из вне...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15457785/2881286

Comment: @Grundy, Благодарю....